# Grep excluding line that ends in 0, but not 10, 100 etc

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep

I have a file that has this pattern in Linux and Unix environments.

```
# file1
text1   98432230
text2    123412
text3        10
line4         0
line5         0
line6     40000
...         ...
line10       20
...         ...
```

I am trying to exclude lines that end with `0`, but not exclude lines ending with `10`, `20`, `40000`, `98432230` and so on.

I have tested ,`|grep -v "\0$"`, `| grep -v "[[:space:]]0$"`, `| grep -v " 0"`, `| sed '/0/d'`, `| sed  "/0$/d"` but none of them work as they exclude any line that ends in 0, including 10, 20, 40000 and 98432230.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure `grep -v "[[:space:]]0$"` and `| grep -v " 0"` didn't work? The second would fail if your file is tab-separated, but the first should work perfectly.

Comment: Try `grep -v "[[:space:]]0$"` again, that ought to have worked.

Comment: Try single quotes (apostrophes) instead of double quotes on the grep -v patterns that include the dollar sign. That is, `grep -v '[[:space:]]0$'` should work. The shell will try to expand the $ inside double quotes and it won't be passed to the grep.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Don't use `grep`, do it in `awk` instead:

```
$ awk '$NF!=0' file
text1   98432230
text2    123412
text3        10
line6     40000
...         ...
line10       20
...         ...
```

In `awk`, the variable `NF` s the number of fields, so `$NF` is the last field. Expressions that evaluate to true mean "print this line" so `$NF!=0` means "print every line whose last field is not 0".

You could even simplify it further to just:

```
awk '$NF' file
```

Comment: Thanks goof alternative, I rarely use awk so didn't trie that.

Comment: Or `$NF != "0"`, if one wants to only exclude lines where the last field consists of that one digit `0` exactly. The default behaviour of awk would be to compare numerically, meaning that `$NF != 0` would also exclude `000`, `0.0`, and `0e42`.   Probably not a problem, perhaps even what one would want, but it's useful to be aware of that.

Comment: @ilkkachu yes, that's precisely why I used `!= 0`, so that `0.0` and `000` etc would also be removed.

Comment: This question (and answers) should be duplicated in codeGolf ;)

Answer (score 4):

For grep, you want a regular expression that matches three things:  a character that is not numeric, followed by a '0', at the end of the line:

```
grep -v '[^0-9]0$'
```

Will you want to also match and discard any lines that end in just two zeroes, `00`?

Comment: Not mentioned in the question, but this will also filter out `12.0` or similar values.

Comment: Thank you, it works, I was thinking I had already tried that one.

Answer (score 3):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
raku -ne '.put if .grep( none / \D 0 $/ );'
```

Above uses Raku's `grep` routine. The regex atom `\D` is a non-digit. This routine takes advantage of Raku's `none` junction, which tests for the absence of the regex match. If you just `put` the return without the `if` conditional, you get the original file back with blank lines where no matches are found.

Sample Input:

```
text1  98432230
text2    123412
text3        10
line4         0
line5         0
line6     40000
line10       20
```

Sample Output:

```
text1  98432230
text2    123412
text3        10
line6     40000
line10       20
```

TMTOWTDI: In this case swapping out `grep` and using  `match` instead gives the same return. Also `match(/…/)` can be written more simply as `m/…/`, and `none` inside the grep/match operator can be swapped with `!` preceeding, as follows. (Special thanks to Bruce Gray for insights/discussion):

```
raku -ne '.put if .match( none / \D 0 $/ );' 

#OR

raku -ne '.put if  ! .match( / \D 0 $/ );'  

#OR

raku -ne '.put if  ! m/ \D 0 $/;'
```

https://docs.raku.org/routine/none
https://docs.raku.org/routine/grep
https://raku.org

Answer (score 3):

You need to match a single 0, so you can say it's a whole "word"

`grep -vw '0$'` will only match (and exclude because of `-v`) lines that end with a "word" 0.

Comment: With the caveat that it'd also drop lines that end in `1.0`. They don't have any in this question here, but it's a reasonable thing someone might have.

Comment: And it will not drop lines ending with something like "a0" as that would be a single word as well.